# In Spock, how can I eliminate duplicated interactions from the "then" block?

Tags: testing, groovy, spock

I am using the Spock testing framework.  I have a lot of tests with a structure similar to this:

```
def "test"() {
    when:
    doSomething()
    then:
    1 * mock.method1(...)
    2 * mock.method2(...)
}
```

I want to move the code of the "then" block to a helper method:

```
def assertMockMethodsInvocations() {
    1 * mock.method1(...)
    2 * mock.method2(...)
}
```

Then invoke this helper method to eliminate the code duplications in my Specification as follows:

```
def "test"() {
    when:
    doSomething()
    then:
    assertMockMethodsInvocations()
}
```

However, I am unable to match method invocations when placing `n * mock.method(...)` in a helper method.  The following example demonstrates:

```
// groovy code
class NoInvocationsDemo extends Specification {

    def DummyService service

    def "test"() {
        service = Mock()

        when:
        service.say("hello")
        service.say("world")

        then:
        assertService()
    }

    private assertService() {
        1 * service.say("hello")
        1 * service.say("world")
        true
    }

}

// java code
public interface DummyService {
    void say(String msg);
}

// [RESULT]
// Too few invocations for:
//
// 1 * service.say("hello")   (0 invocations)
//
// Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):
//
// 1 * service.say('hello')
// 1 * service.say('world')
//
// Too few invocations for:
//
// 1 * service.say("world")   (0 invocations)
//
// Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):
//
// 1 * service.say('world')
// 1 * service.say('hello')
```

How can I remove the duplicated code from my `then:` block?

Comment: great, but do you have a question?

Comment: This feature cannot be used because `n * mock.method(...)` is a syntax sugar. If you use this in another method it will not work as expected. They will not capture any methods invocations. @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I found an easy way to solve this problem. What we need to do is wrapping helper methods in an `interaction` block.

```
then:
interaction {
    assertService()
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about that.  Nice!